# What is an extra move in Mancala, and can you have more than one?

Tags: mancala

When playing mancala, when you get a stone that lands in your mancala and get an extra move, is it just one move or do you start over like in the beginning and pick a group of stones on your side and go unil they run out?  Also, if you end up landing in your own mancala again, do you then get another free move, or is there just one free move before your opponent goes?

Answer (score 5):

***Note**: [Mancala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancala) is actually a family of games, not a game itself. Since you call the game 'Mancala', I'm going to assume you have a commercial Western version of Mancala, which means you're very likely actually playing [Kalah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalah).*

A *move* in Mancala always means "take the group of stones from one of your pits, and sow them all again". So yes, it is just "like in the beginning".

For any move, if the last stone in the move falls on your store, you take another move. You can have many extra moves if you keep finishing your moves in your store.